# Angular Routing - passing json object but param is 1 solid string

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

Im building an app and passing user data around different pages, I have a variable called profileData which is a json type of Profile.

Im passing it in the router like so:

`return this.router.navigate(['/chat-profile', { profile: JSON.stringify(this.profileData)  }]);`

when i navigate to the page the data url i see in the browser is like so

`http://localhost:8100/chat-profile;profile=%7B%22photos%22:%5B%5D,%22uid%22:%22AzvHdHKIYS%22,%22enabled%22:true,%22gps%22:false,%22about%22:%22%22,%22createdAt%22:%222019-04-30T14:34:06.994Z%22,%22updatedAt%22:%222019-04-30T14:34:22.033Z%22,%22gender%22:%22M%22,%22name%22:%22joe%22,%22location%22:%7B%22latitude%22:220.09,%22longitude%2222:14.46%7D,%22age%222:22,%22id%22:%22FbbQseOJFH%22%7D`

When accessing it in the component its just one solid string. How to pass an object in angular routing

Comment: Remove `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: Is having this long URL crucial? If not, I'd consider using the Ionic NavController to push an object and retrieve it with NavParams on another page.

Comment: What is the purpose of passing it in this way? You'd be better off sharing it via a service unless you have a very specific reason for doing this in the URL.

Comment: Why not use shared service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using router params to share such data between component in angular is a bad practice. You should use shared service for that. For more details on different ways to share data between components in angular look at this article:

https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/

Answer (score 3):

You can change to

```
this.router.navigate(['/chat-profile'], 
        { queryParams: { profile: JSON.stringify(this.profileData) }});
```

Get parameter by

```
 this.route.queryParams.subscribe(
      params => {
         let data = JSON.parse(params['profile']);
         console.log('Got param: ', data.longitude);

      }
    )
```

Comment: try this demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-navigate-with-query-params-uvz6q8

Comment: looks like the issue is because im using a custom struct export interface like this IProfile {
  longtitue: number
  name: string
}

Comment: it give the error on json parse Argument of type 'IProfile' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'